# How can I add authentication scope to a GET method on googles API?

Tags: php, android

I have made a script that exchanges my google token for a fresh access key.

Now, I want to check a IAP purchase with my access token (to authenticate).

The google documentation (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) says I must use this GET method:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/products/productId/tokens/token
```

How do I add my access_token to this url to authorize my app to successfully get the data I need returned by the GET method?

I tried:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/flarehubpe.xflare.flarehub/purchases/products/flarehubvip/tokens/fraudtoken_shouldfail" . "&access_token=" . $accessToken
```

But I get the error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

How should I authenticate? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your access_token in the header of request along with url.

Example : Bearer "your access_token"

[image]